# jQuery Mobile Swiping Event for Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a web site that I want to scroll one screen width to the left or right when the user swipes in that direction on their device.  I am using jQuery Mobile and the 'swipeleft' and 'swiperight' events.  I use the preventDefault function to disable the normal panning of the screen but it doesn't work.  Sometimes it works and scrolls the width, but sometimes it just randomly moves the page a certain amount to the left or right. It works if I swipe with the mouse on my PC, but not all the time on devices. Any idea?

```
$( "body" ).on( "swipeleft", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ScrollPageLeft() });
$( "body" ).on( "swiperight", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ScrollPageRight() });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: This prevents any touching behavior, so this answer is no good.